# Sorting a specific taxonomy by archive date using URL

Tags: filters, taxonomy, archives

OK, so I'm looking for a way to sort a specific taxonomy by archive date using the site URL.

Say the custom taxonomy ("sort") value is "fruit" then then you would currently get all the posts marked as fruit with a link like this:

```
http://mysite.com/sort/fruit/
```

And to filter by archive date you will use:

```
http://mysite.com/date/2013/
```

The question is, is there a way to combine these 2 urls to just get posts marked as fruit in 2013?

I tried `/sort/fruit/date/2013` and `/date/2013/sort/fruit/` and in both cases it just gives me an empty page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you accept `/sort/fruit/?date=2013`, or does it have to be `/sort/fruit/date/2013`?

Comment: I can work with the 1st option too eh